# How Can I Get Data from Script to Populate ChoiceField in Django

Tags: django, ajax, django-views

I'm working on an app for golfing. i'm stuck right now trying to do have a user enter in a course name, and return the result. When the user clicks a button, I use a beautifulSoup script to scrape a scorecard database website based on the input name.

Right now i'm just trying to test out a user entering a course, and seeing the results returned in the AJAX response so I can further my javascript, but i'm not seeing anything. If I print the results from the views.py though, I can see it returned successfully. I just don't know how to attached that view response to return to the ajax call.

Here is my code:

views.py

```
def lookupCourses(request, courseName):
    course_result = course_query(courseName)
    return JsonResponse(course_result)
```

urls.py

```
app_name='golf_courses'

urlpatterns = [
    path('add/', Golf_CourseCreateView.as_view(), name='add'),
    path(r'lookup/<str:courseName>/', lookupCourses, name='lookup'),
```

]

courses.js

```
'use strict';
 const courseNameBtn = document.getElementById('button-addon2');

 const getCountryData = function () {

 const courseName = document.getElementById('id_courseLookup').value
 fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/golf_courses/lookup/${courseName}/`)
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    return response;
  });
};
courseNameBtn.addEventListener('click', getCountryData)
```

course_parse.py

```
def course_query(course):
# COURSE_QUERY = sys.argv[1]
COURSE_QUERY = course

URL = "https://www.mscorecard.com/mscorecard/courses.php?CourseName={}&Country=USA&SubmitButton=Search".format(COURSE_QUERY)
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
page_body = soup.find("div", class_="page-content")

matching_courses = page_body.find_all("a", class_="no-hover")


course_dict = {}
for i, course in enumerate(matching_courses):
    course_location = course.find("div", class_="course-location")
    row = course.find("div", class_="col-md-6")
    course_name = row.find('div', attrs={'style': 'font-size: 18px; color: black; font-weight: 600'})
    
    formal_name = '{} - {}'.format(course_name.text, course_location.text.strip())
    course_dict[i] = formal_name
return course_dict
```

Again, I can go the the view and print the result and see the data gets returned, I just don't know how to get it to show up in the AJAX response so I can then use the response to populate the Choicefield.

Form
[image]

Comment: So after doing some research, it looks like in the ajax call, I needed to grab the data -_-

const courseName = document.getElementById('id_courseLookup').value
    fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/golf_courses/lookup/${courseName}/`)
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (data) {
        console.log(data)
    })
};

Will update when I have everything fully functioning

Comment: Do you use jquery library on the site or any other JS framework?

Answer (score 0):

For ES6 - I was able to accomplish this by using the data value returned from fetch. Then with the data I create select options.

in the ajax call:

```
const courseChoices = document.getElementById('id_courseChoices');
const courseName = document.getElementById('id_courseLookup').value

fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/golf_courses/lookup/${courseName}/`)
.then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
})
.then(function (data) {
    Object.entries(data).forEach(element => {
        const option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = element[1];
        option.text = element[0];
        courseChoices.appendChild(option);   
    });
})
```